# $.ajax like function for Node js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

is Node js has any function just like $.ajax? I think Node js is fully javascript written and $.ajax jquery is also is fully javascript written. Then maybe node js has any function just like $.ajax. Is it wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/request/request

Comment: ajax is for frontend to query backend. since nodejs is alrdy in backend, why would u need ajax?

Comment: @Mox He/she probably wants to send a typical http request to another server or an internal application-level route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, AJAX is a browser-only thing based on a particular API in the browser.  So, I will assume that what you're really asking about is for a simple way to make HTTP requests of other HTTP servers from within node.js.

To make such a request, you can either use the built-in `http.get()` (in the http module) or you can use a higher level add-on module [`request()`](https://github.com/request/request).  The request module is built on top of the `http` module, but offers many more features and, for many things, it much easier to use.

Among the list of features in the request module, you will find: stream support,  form encoding/decoding, http auth, custom headers, OAuth, signing, redirects, queryString, gzip, etc...

Here's an example:

```
const request = require('request');

request({method: 'GET', uri: 'http://www.google.com'}, function(err, response, body) {
    // handle response here
});
```

Since promises are now the more modern tool for handling asynchronous operations in Javascript, here's an example using promises:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

rp({method: 'GET', uri: 'http://www.google.com'}).then(body => {
    // handle response here
}).catch(err => {
    // error here
});
```

---

**EDIT Jan, 2020 - request() module in maintenance mode**

FYI, the `request` module and its derivatives like [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) are now in maintenance mode and will not be actively developed to add new features.  You can read more about the reasoning [here](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode).  There is a list of alternatives in [this table](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode#alternativestorequest) with some discussion of each one.  I have been using [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) myself and it's built from the beginning to use promises and is simple to use.